# glMultiDrawArraysIndirect instanceID and basInstance behaves differently passing all draw calls at once?

Tags: opengl, opengl-4

When I toggle between these two ways of drawing a vector of `DrawArraysIndirectCommand`, the passed `gl_BaseInstance` read in the vertex-shader is different. In the latter case, gl_BasInstance is always 0.
To my understanding the result should be the same, each commands `gl_InstanceID` should start from zero, and the `gl_BaseInstance` should be the `baseInstance` member of the `DrawArraysIndirectCommand` struct.

Am I wrong here, should there be a difference passing each command one at a time versus passing all commands at once?

```
auto commands = std::vector<DrawArraysIndirectCommand>{...};

// A - Pass each command one at a time
for (const auto& command : commands) {
    glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(GL_TRIANGLES, &command, 1, 0);
}

// B - Pass all commands as an array
glMultiDrawArraysIndirect(
    GL_TRIANGLES,
    commands.data(),
    commands.size(),
    0
);

// 
typedef  struct {
   GLuint count;
   GLuint instanceCount;
   GLuint first;
   GLuint baseInstance;
} DrawArraysIndirectCommand;
```

Note: I'm using OpenGL 4.6

Comment: You seem to be reading the indirect data directly from CPU memory. I'm pretty sure that's not allowed for indirect rendering. At least in a core OpenGL context.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thanks, it worked using a buffer. Weirdly the documentation does not say anything about this. It says: "If a buffer is bound to the GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER binding at the time of a call to glMultiDrawArraysIndirect" making me believe that I can use CPU memory as well.
(https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMultiDrawArraysIndirect.xhtml)

Comment: In the [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)  is clearly specified, that *"An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated if zero is bound to DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER"* (page 367)

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thanks, I didn't check the specification, only read the khronos.org documentation referred to, (and for some reason I didn't get any error, but I was running the context in SDL compatibility mode)